# Zeroclipboard-rails not working but no error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, zeroclipboard

I'm trying to use Zeroclipboard (via gem `zeroclipboard-rails`) in my project, but it doesn't work and I have no error.

This is my script:

```js
$(document).on("ready page:change", function () {
  var client = new ZeroClipboard($("#copyToClipboard"));

  client.on("complete", function (client, args) {
    alert("Text successfully copied");
  });
});

$(document).on("page:before-change", function () {
  ZeroClipboard.destroy();
});
```

I also tried:

```js
$(document).on("ready page:change", function () {
  var client = new ZeroClipboard($("#copyToClipboard"));

  client.on("load", function (client) {
    client.on("complete", function (client, args) {
      alert("Text successfully copied");
    });
  });
});

$(document).on("page:before-change", function () {
  ZeroClipboard.destroy();
});
```

I'm able to log the `client` var but nothing within `complete` event.

I found this doc: https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard/blob/master/docs/api/ZeroClipboard.md

So i tried to replace `load` with `ready`, then `complete` with `aftercopy` but no effects...

My slim code:

```
#contentForClipboard.d-none
  = simple_format(h proposition.content)

[...]

= button_tag id: 'copyToClipboard', 'data-clipboard-target' => 'contentForClipboard', class: "btn btn-light btn-sm clip_button" do
  => fa_icon('fas', 'clipboard')
  | Copy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

zeroclipboard relies on Adobe Flash, that is being phased out (EOL scheduled in 2020), and already it is not enabled by default in modern browsers.

You can try libraries like [clipboard.js](https://clipboardjs.com/) that rely on modern browser support (`Selection` and `execCommand`) and do not require any flash.